# Dedup and get max valued row for a key in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects. This array has duplicate rows. Need to identify deduped rows with one of the keys having max value. Please not e it is already a sorted by id.

```
var myArray = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'jenny@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'jenny@bar.com'},
];
```

This is the sample array of objects. I need to get the following as output

```
var myArray = [  
  {id: 3, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'jenny@bar.com'},
];



for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = i + 1; j < myArray.length; j++) {
        if (myArray[i].name === myArray[j].name && myArray[i].email === myArray[j].email) {
            myArray.splice(j,1);
        }
    }
}
```

the code works only if there are 2 duplicates. I want something that works for more than 2 duplicates and includes only the row with max id

Comment: Do you need to keep in place the items with the max value of the `id`, or `id` equals to `1` is OK?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand but if you are asking if I would need to keep the order as oriiginal. Yes, I would need to keep it.

Comment: Do you need to keep the last one (in array order) that matches or the one with the highest id?

Comment: the one with highest id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for same name and email in the accumulator and push if not found or update if `id` is smaller.

```js
var array = [{ id: 1, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com' }, { id: 2, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com' }, { id: 3, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com' }, { id: 1, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'jenny@bar.com' }, { id: 2, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'jenny@bar.com' }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        var index = r.findIndex(p => o.name === p.name && o.email === p.email);
        if (index === -1) {
            r.push(o);
            return r;
        }
        if (r[index].id < o.id) {
            r[index] = o;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It behaves this way because `myArray.splice` reduces the length of the initial array, and some indexes may be skipped. To avoid this, you can iterate from the end to the beginning of the array and do `i--` right after the `splice` operation, it should help to keep the right order of your iteration. The provided array is already sorted by id in ascending order (I mean those objects with the same `name` and `email`), and this way you will get the unique objects with the highest `id`:

```js
var myArray = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Foo Bar', email: 'foo@bar.com'},
  {id: 1, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'jenny@bar.com'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Jenny Block', email: 'jenny@bar.com'},
];

for (var i = myArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (myArray[i].name === myArray[j].name && myArray[i].email === myArray[j].email) {
            myArray.splice(j,1);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var maxId = 0;
var duplicates = [];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++) {
    maxId = myArray[i].id;
    if(!duplicates.includes(i)) {
        for (var j = i+1; j < myArray.length; j++) {  
            if (myArray[j].id > maxId) {
                maxId = myArray[j].id; 
                duplicates.push[j]; 
            }  
        }
    }
    myArray[i].id = maxId;
    newArray.push(myArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one take that starts with a generic function for problems of this sort: deduping a list of values by accepting two functions, one generating a key for those that match, and a second to choose which of a pair of matching values to keep.

We can supply something like `` ({name, email}) => `${name}~${email}` `` for key generation, but I choose to use `JSON.stringify` on everything but the `id` instead, as it seems more flexible.  And choosing the correct matching one is simply `(a, b) => a.id > b.id ? a : b`

```js
const dedupe = (genKey, choose) => xs => Object.values(xs.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const key = genKey(x)
  acc[key] = acc[key] ? choose(acc[key], x) : x
  return acc
}, {}))

const keepHighestId = dedupe(
  ({id, ...rest}) => JSON.stringify(rest), 
  (a, b) => a.id > b.id ? a : b
)

const myArray = [{"email": "foo@bar.com", "id": 1, "name": "Foo Bar"}, {"email": "foo@bar.com", "id": 2, "name": "Foo Bar"}, {"email": "foo@bar.com", "id": 3, "name": "Foo Bar"}, {"email": "jenny@bar.com", "id": 1, "name": "Jenny Block"}, {"email": "jenny@bar.com", "id": 2, "name": "Jenny Block"}]

console.log(keepHighestId(myArray))
```

Adding such abstractions is clearly not always the best option, but it can help to break down the problem into more manageable pieces.